# When did Bruce Wayne get the amnesia shown in Red Hood/Arsenal #5

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52, dc-rebirth

I'm reading Red Hood/Arsenal, and at the end of issue #5 Jason goes back to Lucius Fox's centre, and he finds Bruce, but  as an amnesiac. How did that happen? When did this series of events occur? Was it in the New 52, Rebirth? I'm so lost with the reboot stuff.

[image: Jason find Bruce]

Comment: Are you asking how Jason found Bruce "amnesic" which I guess mean as an amnesiac?

Comment: I'm asking how Bruce get  **amnesiac**, And in which reboot this is happening

Comment: Ah i understand, I've not read them myself but I'm sure someone could tell you

Comment: Are you sure this happens in #4? Can you provide a image from the comic?

Comment: My bad, it's #5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Batman Vol 2 #43](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_2_43)

In Batman Vol 2 #40. Batman is supposedly killed when a warehouse collapses on him and Joker.

In #43 it is revealed that although Bruce had died, he'd come back to life. But the neural pathways in his brain had completely changed.

[image: Alfred talking to Supes about Bruce's amnesia]

Kent wants to reveal to the new Bruce Wayne that he is Batman, but Alfred informs him he has lost **all** his knowledge from the past 15 years of his training.

Comment: So.. this will  be New 52?

Comment: Exactly. Vol2 is New 52 published around mid 2015

Comment: Is not compiled in one bock just yet, right?

Comment: It looks like it was sold as Batman Vol 2: City of Owls

Comment: It seems I lied. That's not the right thing.